# NodeJs not installing properly - ubuntu 16.06

Tags: node.js

I have followed [This digital ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04) for installing node . and when i tried to run command sudo apt-get install npm it gave me error that

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I removed it completely using [This Post](https://askubuntu.com/a/786019) and install nodeJs again using [This NVM tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps) It ended successfully installing .I made app.js with "hello world" as response and run the command node app.js and when i hit the localhost:3000 it showed Hello world - But once i closed my terminal and run node app.js it failed saying 
The program 'node' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install nodejs-legacy
while i have done that before . It only runs again if i follow all the steps of nvm installation again

Comment: try run with "nodejs app.js"

Answer (score -1):

please try below command to install nodejs.

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
    sudo apt-get install npm
    sudo npm install n -g
     version is:`-- n@2.1.4 



*following commands are used to run nodejs program
node
>console.log("Hello World!");
above command print hello world in cmd

ctrl+d is used to terminate from cmd
```

Comment: sorry buddy .. my error resolved don't know why .... but i'll accept it as an answer as soon as it get two upvote - thanks